# Using Multiple-GPU + CL-GL Interop Buffers

Tags: opencl

I have implemented a simple code with opencl which copies 64MB data using 16 Mthreads. The kernel is as follows:

```
__kernel void myKernel(
  __global float4* a,
  __global float4* c,
  int count
  ){ 

  int thread_idx = get_global_id(0);
  if (thread_idx >= count) return;

  c[thread_idx] = a[thread_idx]; 
}
```

My computer has two Graphic Cards (GTX 980 + GTX 970) and one display. I am using Windows 8.1. I have created `c[...]` buffer on the host, once using normal `clCreateBuffer` and another time creating a gl buffer with opengl and creating a cl buffer with `clCreateFromGLBuffer`. My comparsions showed that the buffers created with `clCreateBuffer` are always of the same speed slow, but the GL buffer which is created on the gpu which is connected to display is much more faster as is shown in the diagrams:

[image: Kernel Code]
[image: GTX 980 is connected to the display]
[image: GTX 970 is connected to the display]

My investigation shows that the `clEnqueueAcquireGLBuffer` is making everything slower on the gpu which is not connected to the display. Anyone have ever seen such problem? And know how can I fix it?

The complete code can be found here: https://github.com/mmostajab/TestGPUMem_CL

Comment: This is not a  problem, just a card has 200 GB/s bandwidth with vram to vram copy. Pci-e lane (to non-rendering card) has only 8-16 GB/s maybe less for small data. If you are directly using that shared buffer, then there is no copy vs pci-e copy comparison. You can load balance such as giving only 8MB part through the other card and 56 MB on rendering device.

Comment: I didn't get it. So, the problem is that the data which I am going to generate is even bigger than this. As I understood if I have two cl contexts on two gpus, the gpus will always work fast but if we create one context on one gpu, the other one needs to transfer the data from the one which owns the context and then it becomes slow.

Comment: Do you display any result?

Comment: With/without displaying, the results are almost the same.

Comment: Then make the data copy at the same time with previous iterations so you can halve the time for this.